# ASLR on i686-pae vs amd64 kernels running 32bit processes

Tags: security, linux-kernel, 64bit, pae, aslr

Is ASLR more, same or less secure for a process running on an i686-pae kernel or for a 32bit process running on an amd64 kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Address Space Layout Randomization is just as ineffective for a 32-bit process regardless if it is running in 32-bit compatibility mode on a 64-bit kernel, or on a 32-bit kernel. Both ways the user process has only a limited amount of address bits to randomize, reducing the number of possible positions to place things. PAE also does not affect ASLR, since it is just a mechanism to increase the amount of addressable physical memory.

KASLR (Kernel ASLR) is a different matter, it will benefit from running in Long Mode (64-bit) on x86-64.